# How to exclude *.desginer.* documents from filtered search in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, filter, settings

This question is about the [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to?view=vs-2019#filter-to-a-specific-location) in Visual Studio (2022), reachable by <kbd>CTRL + T</kbd>.
*(It is not about the Search with <kbd>CTRL + F</kbd>)*

If I don't want to see all the automatically generated entries in `*.designer.*` documents using the filter function, how can I exclude them?

I know that I can use the scope restriction in the upper right corner of the filter box [image: 2] to "Search current document only". But I would like to search my entire project and exclude only the mentioned `*.designer.*` documents.

Is there any setting for this filter restriction?
Or do you know any workaround to see only useful filter locations?

Answer (score 0):

Below patter works for me VS2022.

```
*.aspx;*.ascx;*.cshtml;*.cs;!*.designer.cs;
```

Comment: Where do I have to enter your code line to exclude *.designer.cs  from the filter with CTRL+T?